# SOQL to get Apex Test class code coverage doesn't show the result

Tags: soql

I have simply modified the below query in order to get the code coverage in %,

**SOQL:**

> select id,apexClassorTrigger.Name,numLinescovered, numlinesuncovered from apexcodecoverageAggregate

When I tried below query it gives me

> select id,apexClassorTrigger.Name,numLinescovered, numlinesuncovered,Coverage from apexcodecoverageAggregate

@Ref: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_apexcodecoverageaggregate.htm

[image]

Comment: Did you actually read the documentation you linked to? It could hardly be more clear about the structure of the data in the `Coverage` field.

Answer (score 1):

Coverage is a complex value that shows the individual line numbers that are covered and not covered. Unfortunately, to get the coverage percentage yourself, you'll have to calculate it in a spreadsheet or a program you'd write in some language. The formula is simply:

```
NumLinesCovered/(NumLinesCovered+NumLinesUncovered)
```

You can call the Tooling API from Apex Code or JavaScript in Visualforce, or a language of your choice (Ruby, Perl, PHP, etc).